# RED Editor in Eclipse throws Exception while opening the .robot suite file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, robotframework, java-io

1. I am generating a robot suite file using a java program, which generates .robot file using UTF-8 Encoding
2. Trying to open generated Robot suite file using RED Editor in Eclipse Mars

**3. Throws below exception, need to figureout why? and probable soultion.**

4. Note that other robot files created using RED Editor can be opened without this error
5. Also note that, Robot files generated using java program are opened properly using notepad++ and vim

**Sample Robot suite file:**

```
*** Settings ***
Library     some.class.path.ClassName

*** Keywords ***
type val
    [Arguments]     ${xpathForLocale}       ${dataModifyRole}       ${strLocale}    
     some.class.path.ClassName.type     ${xpathForLocale}       ${dataModifyRole}       ${strLocale}
```

**Exception:**

```
org.robotframework.ide.eclipse.main.plugin.tableeditor.RobotFormEditor$IllegalRobotEditorInputException: Unable to open editor: unrecognized input of class: org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput
    at org.robotframework.ide.eclipse.main.plugin.tableeditor.RobotFormEditor.setInput(RobotFormEditor.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.init(FormEditor.java:128)
    at org.robotframework.ide.eclipse.main.plugin.tableeditor.RobotFormEditor.init(RobotFormEditor.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:319)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1163)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3234)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3126)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3090)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3071)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(IDE.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenLocalFileAction.run(OpenLocalFileAction.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenLocalFileAction.run(OpenLocalFileAction.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

**Options tried so-far - which didn't work**

1. dos2unix conversion
2. Generated Robot file using other encoding formats like UTF-16 and CP1252
3. Changed Eclipse > Windows> Preferences > Workspace > Text File Encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to open a file which is not in your workspace. Some editors don't support this.

Comment: I had the file available in the workspace.

Comment: have you tried contacting the author of the RED extension? Stackoverflow isn't for customer support.

Comment: Not yet, will do now. Hope they are still active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug with RED Editor: https://github.com/nokia/RED/issues/21
To be fixed in next available release

Comment: The bug listed above is fixed now.

Comment: i still cant open robot files with Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not correct. The spacings are irregular (should be 4 spaces).
It is missing the Test Cases section.

Here is a corrected file which opens correctly in [RIDE](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE):

```
*** Settings ***
Library        some.class.path.ClassName

*** Test Cases ***
Some Test
    No Operation

*** Keywords ***
type val
    [Arguments]    ${xpathForLocale}   ${dataModifyRole}    ${strLocale}    
    some.class.path.ClassName.type    ${xpathForLocale}    ${dataModifyRole}    ${strLocale}
```

Comment: The sample is a keyword resource file. Despite that, these errors are syntax errors, and should not cause RED editor not to display the contents of the file and throw those Eclipse exceptions.